# Timidity output changes when using -Ox options to output to file

Tags: audio, midi

I'm using `timidity` to convert MIDI files to ogg vorbis files. However, the output is musically different.

By musically different, I mean they are in the different [key](https://enwp.org/Key_(music)). They are also played in different speed.

I'm using a custom soundfont file, the following is the entirety of my config file.

```
$ cat /usr/local/share/timidity/timidity.cfg
dir /usr/local/share/timidity/soundfonts
soundfont Touhou.sf2
# source fluid3gm.cfg
# trysource fluid3gs.cfg
# source fluid_altassign.cfg
```

The MIDI file in question may be obtained from [here](https://thwiki.cc/File:th07_04.mid) ([Direct download](https://upload.thwiki.cc/9/99/th07_04.mid)). The soundfont [here](https://musical-artifacts.com/artifacts/433).

For reference, to my ears, the first few notes are

```
G bE C bE G [C] G bE [D] [C]
```

(`[x]` = higher `x`)

when invoked like this: `$ timidity ./th07_04.mid`.

When outputted to OGG file via `-Ov`, the first few notes are

```
#F D {B} D #F B #F D [#C] B
```

(`{x}` = lower `x`)

Any ideas why?

---

Here is my current test results, H means Higher (G...) and L means Lower (#F...)

| Software | macOS Monterey | Fedora 36 | Windows 11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Straight from timidity | H | L | L |
| Output to file | L | L | L |

Thus, the music is only higher when its set to directly output on macOS.

Comment: I have no idea why, but you can test if this is related to ogg vorbis or to file output vs. direct sound by trying other formats (e.g. `-Ow`, `-OF`)

Comment: @dirkt Ow is the same, so I wrote -Ox in the title

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you don't use a custom soundfont? Does the same thing happen with a completely unrelated midi file? If yes, can you use a tool to determine the actual frequencies in the WAV file without playing it? E.g. Audacity has a FFT feature. (The purpose of those tests is to narrow down the place where it goes wrong, by exchanging parts of the whole process).

Comment: @dirkt I tested (with the same config) on another Fedora box I have, the output is the same as -Ov produces (even when I listen to timidity directly) here on my Mac.

Comment: This is not surprising and doesn't help narrow down the problem, as the code on the Fedora box is the same as on the Mac. It rules out problems with the sound hardware, though. I'd still try without soundfonts first, to see if the problem is with something in the soundfonts.

Comment: @dirkt You misunderstood me. I just tested on Windows and the result is Lower. Thus, the bug is reproduced **if and only if** the program is being run on mac, and set to direct output to sound.

Comment: Then my guess would be a mismatch between sample rate timidity assumes and actual sample rate of the audio device on MacOS. Which I guess is a bug, you may try filing a bug report with the timitidy developers.